# C Modify String in Function Parameter and Dereference

Tags: c, string, dereference

A bit new to C here, but this is what I'm working on.

```
void do_something(char* str){
  char *new = str[0]+1;
  printf("%s%s\n", *str, new);

}

int main(){
  char input[2];
  printf("Enter a two character string: \n");
  scanf("%s", input);
  do_something(&input);
}
```

Here's my expected output for`do_something()`

```
do_something("aa")
.
.
.
aaba
```

Basically in `do_something()` I want to print the dereferenced input parameter `str`, and then a modified version of the parameter where the first character is incremented by one using ascii.

I'm not sure if I'm passing in the correct input into the function inside of my `main()` function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to understand that C strings are NUL terminated character arrays. `new` is not a C string. And neither is `*str`. In fact, even `input` is not a valid C string as it requires an array of 3 `chars` to store a 2 character string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I'm passing in the correct input into the function inside of my main() function.

No that's incorrect.

`do_something(&input);` // incorrect because input is already string

You should pass the parameter as

`do_something(input);`

Also this declaration looks really troubling, and not what you want:

```
char input[2]; // this can only hold 1 char (and the other for NUL character)
```

You should really have bigger buffer, and DO allocate for the NUL character as well, something like

```
char input[100] = ""; // can hold upto 99 chars, leaving 1 space for NUL
```

---

> Basically in do_something() I want to print the dereferenced input parameter str, and then a modified version of the parameter where the first character is incremented by one using ascii.

You can directly modify the string inside function `do_something` (and no need to create another pointer in it - atm it was completely wrong)

```
void do_something(char* str){
    // char *new = str[0]+1;  // <-- remove this
    str[0] += 1;   // <-- can change the string passed from `main` directly here
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: But that only prints the modified string. I want to know if there's a way to get the string from the parameter, modify it and store it in a variable, then print the modified and original strings on one line. See the expected result.

Comment: then you need to allocate a different string inside `do_something`, example `char input2[100] = "";` then `strcpy` from the parameter to that `input2` and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void do_something(char* str)
{
    char new = ++str[0];
    printf("%c %s\n", new, str);
}
```